# ES Aggregation query to fetch parent docs based on conditions applied on aggregation results of child docs in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using ES v7.3 and I have parent-child mapping in my index, I want to qualify parent docs in my index based on some aggregation results applied on child docs but I am not able to do so, here is a reference to what I need...

Index Mapping:

```
PUT example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "join": {
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "user": "session"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Parent Doc:

```
PUT example/_doc/1
{
  "join": {
    "name": "user"
  },
  "type": "identify",
  "device": "xx"
  "profileId": "1052210",
  "updatedAt": "2020-12-30T17:06:22.851Z"
}
```

1st Child Doc:

```
PUT example/_doc/2?routing=1
{
  "join": {
    "name": "session",
    "parent": "1"
  },
  "page_view_count": 10,
  "creation_date": "2020-12-30T13:45:37.851Z"
}
```

2nd Child Doc:

```
PUT example/_doc/3?routing=1
{
  "join": {
    "name": "session",
    "parent": "1"
  },
  "page_view_count": 20,
  "creation_date": "2020-12-30T13:45:37.851Z"
}
```

Requirement:

1. Users that have page_view_count > 25 in last 7 days, so we wanted to aggregate the page_view_count in the child docs and check if their sum is > 25 or not, if it satisfies the condition then we should get the parent doc in response otherwise not.

NOTE: These child docs gets formed for each users session and hence the counts are maintained in session wise ES docs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution with only profileId returned:

```
POST example/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "profileId.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sessions": {
          "children": {
            "type" : "session" 
          },
          "aggs": {
            "last_7_days": {
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "creation_date": {
                    "gte": "now-7d",
                    "lte": "now"
                  }
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "page_view_count": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "page_view_count"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "page_view_count_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "viewCount": "sessions > last_7_days > page_view_count"
            },
            "script": "params.viewCount >= 25"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is aggregation supported to run along with scrolling in ES, I don't think so, because I scroll my result docs having chunk size of 10k, but using this bucket_selector aggregation I don't think this can be done??

Comment: I don‘t think it is supported yet. Maybe you can ask on their (elasticsearch) github repo.

Comment: Is there any other way to paginate the aggregation results as there will be lakhs of docs qualifying and also several such counts will be maintained in the child docs on whom conditions will be applied simultaneously, I don't think this solution will be feasible as per my requirements can you suggest me a different approach where I can make some changes to my schema and store session wise counts as such that I am able to query them as per date range without performing any aggregation on them.

Comment: Well, please ask another question (join aggregation is answered here I think) for how to get this use case with join aggregation to be avoided for being able to use scrolling (and reference this question/answer please). One thing I have in mind is that you can postprocess your session documents updating the related parent so you can just filter for those user object with the count, but may be complex.

Comment: Regarding this use case, you‘re looking for a streaming related solution, consider to use kafka where you have such features like count for a time window or range very easy.